# Mouse Jumps all around in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad

I just ran apt upgrade and apt autoremove on my laptop (with a touchpad and a touchscreen) and now my mouse is acting bizarre. When I attempt to move the mouse it jumps all around the screen and when I am not touching the trackpad the mouse cursor just wiggles back and forth. In addition when I am using the two finger scroll option it sometimes randomly moves in the wrong direction for a second, before switching back to the correct direction. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Toshiba Satellite L15W-B1208D.

Unlike many other posts, this issue is unrelated to whether or not I am typing. I have tried adjusting the sensitivity but that has not made a difference. I have also tried looking through my xorg.conf.d folder but have not found any suspicious options in the files.

Thanks in advance for any possible suggestions.

Comment: I have the same problem - it's a bit random, but sometimes the mouse pointer jumps to some other point, sometimes an application behaves as if the wheel had been moved (which it hadn't, at that point). I don't think it's related to any keyboard or touchpad/touchscreen usage (it's a "real" mouse that I use and while I use it, I don't use any of the other devices) - so I haven't really found any matching bugreport on it yet.

Comment: I get this too. Completely bizarre.

Comment: I have the same problem. Mouse pointer some time does not move.. some time it moves randomly... some times it moves itself...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. I tried everything to solve, then I realized what was causing the problem. It only happened after I opened Firefox. So I uninstalled Firefox and installed Chromium and the problem is now gone. Very excited!

Comment: I find this incredible. Please do report this as a bug to the Firefox devs.